# Reveal part of image with blurry/gradient edge on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve this effect.

[image: Reveal Background on hover]

I used the pen by [Nikolay Talanov](https://codepen.io/suez/pen/PwKZwO) for the reveal effect, I've tried to make the edges of the revealing circle blurry using box shadow to make it look closer to the wanted effect but is not quite similar.

Anyone has another solution or approach to make it look the same?

https://codepen.io/dlarkiddo/pen/RxMaVv

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="reveal"></div>
</div>
```

Css

```
   html, body {
       font-size: 62.5%;
       height: 100%;
       overflow: hidden;
   }

  .background {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      background: #000000;
      padding: 20rem;
      text-align: center;
      background: url("http://www.wallpapers4u.org/wp-content/uploads/paper_patterns_backgrounds_textures_lines_36212_1920x1080.jpg") 50% 50% no-repeat fixed;
  }

  .reveal {
      z-index: 5;
      position: absolute;
      top: calc(50% - 10rem);
      left: calc(50% - 10rem);
      width: 20rem;
      height: 20rem;
      background: url("http://gallery.hd.org/_exhibits/textures/text-sample-of-old-novel-DHD.jpg") 50% 50% no-repeat 

  fixed;
      background-size: cover;
      border-radius: 100%;
      box-shadow: 0 0 9em 10em #ffffff inset,0 0 9em 10em #ffffff;
  }
```

Js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var $reveal = $(".reveal"),
     revealWHalf = $reveal.width() / 2;
     $(document).on("mousemove", function(e) {
         $reveal.css({"left": e.pageX - revealWHalf, "top": e.pageY - revealWHalf});
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You img url was incorrect. But anyway, what you need to do is apply a mask.

For instance:

```
.reveal {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 10rem);
  left: calc(50% - 10rem);
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/Im9luhE.png") 50% 50% no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 36%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%);
}
```

https://codepen.io/facundocorradini/pen/jYzMOe

Adjust the gradient as needed.

Downside is, that mask syntax is webkit-only, and like, **totally** deprecated. For current syntax [use the current declaration of mask and use a SVG](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/). 
Hope that guides you enough, I'd do it with SVG but already spend too much time in this (great!) challenge.

Cheers!

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I was looking for. I'll take the advice to use a SVG. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would propably use clip-path for this to show only part of the background and for the reveal element I use a radial-gradient to create the shadow effect.

This can also work with content and not only background image.

Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $reveal = $(".reveal"),
    revealWHalf = $reveal.width() / 2;
  $(document).on("mousemove", function(e) {
    $reveal.css({
      "left": e.pageX,
      "top": e.pageY
    });
    $('.background').css('clip-path', 'circle(80px at ' + e.pageX + 'px ' + e.pageY + 'px)');
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(https://lorempixel.com/1000/800/)
}

.background {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1px;
  background: url("https://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/");
  clip-path: circle(80px at 50px 50px);
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(80px at 50px 50px);
}

.reveal {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 165px;
  height: 165px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, transparent 20%, #fff 70%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background">
  <h1>I am a title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </p>
  <div class="reveal"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice alternative approach. It seems to generate a really thin border though, any idea where that comes from?

Comment: @FacundoCorradini this is from the gradient unfortunately :/

Comment: @FacundoCorradini it's fixed now, i made the element to be bigger than the clip path so this line is hidden

Comment: I was trying to find another solution since the gradient generates a border line, nice alternative to use content.

Comment: @dlarkiddo we can always fix it or replace the gradient with shadow also ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It's the img src you used that's wrong... You gave the webpage instead of a image... Check my output for a different image...

Replaced this...

```
background: url("http://gallery.hd.org/_exhibits/textures/text-sample-of-old-novel-DHD.jpg") 50% 50% no-repeat
```

With this...

```
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/Im9luhE.png") 50% 50% no-repeat
```

**Codepen link:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vpRKOB

Comment: nice catch on the img, but not the effect he wants to achieve

Comment: Thanks for the catch I thought I leaved it fine, from all the changes I made in the code pen it slipped out. Anyway @FacundoCorradini got the effect I was looking for.